# GameKit turn-based matches and communication with server error

Tags: ios9, game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

When sending a turn, endTurnWithNextParticipants frequently (perhaps 30%-50% of the time) gives: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server." However, after sending the turn and getting this error, from the point of the view of the player who sent the turn, it appears that the turn has been successfully sent. The sending player is able to reload the match. The match data reloaded from GC is the same as the match data that was just sent. But it seems that if this is the first turn in the match, for next participant the turn never got received. Yet if it is not the first turn in the match, for the next participant, the turn is usually still received, despite the error. Thus, it seems there is only a serious problem when you get this error and you are attempting to send the first turn in the match. This was not a problem for me in iOS8, but is now in iOS9. Has anyone seen such a problem (and similar turn-based match server communication issues in iOS9)? Is there something I can do to workaround the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the underlying error:

```
NSDictionary *uInfo = error.userInfo;
NSError *underError = [uInfo objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
NSLog("UnderError: %d, %@", underError.code, underError.description);
```

And checking underError.code  and underError.description for more info. I've seen the top level error return generic errors, but the underlying error tell you exactly what the real problem is.